# Cannot login with cached credentials when laptop is locked and off the network

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

So when the computer is in the domain, everything is fine.  When the computer is locked and not connected to the network, it will not login using cached credentials.  However, if the laptop is rebooted and still not connected to the network, it will login using the cached credentials.

Is there a way to solve this problem without having to restart the laptop.

Comment: Any event in the Windows logs that might help here? I would check the security log to start.

Comment: Some questions for you to better help you: - Does this happen with every user profile or only one specific user?
- Does it given any error when trying to login with this method such as "The system cannot log you on now because the domain is not available."?
- What version of server is your DC running ? 2003 or 08?
- Can you check the logs when this happens and respond with what error it might give if any? (a common one for this problem is "Event 5719 NETLOGON") This article from microsoft may contain some help until you respond to my questions:
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172931

Comment: It happens to all user profile for 2 Dell laptop.  The rest are all Lenovo and they are fine.

The error is saying "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.

The DC is 2008

Comment: Have you modified the number of cached logins to remember? The default is 10, but if it's lower I can see you running into this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You most likely have [Interactive Logon: Require Domain Controller authentication to unlock](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779612(v=ws.10).aspx) enabled in Group Policy for these laptops.

`gpresult`, `rsop.msc` and the other usual GPO troubleshooting techniques should confirm this pretty quickly.

Comment: I am seeing this same issue.  I verified that this policy here is not enabled or "Not Defined".  However, this issue persists for us with Dell Latitude E5570s.   We do not see this issue with the HP laptops on our network.